# "Spell check" vs. "spelling check"

Tags: word-choice, nouns, gerunds

I can't remember the exact place I saw this (but I believe it was on another StackExchange site), but when someone was commenting on a software's "spell check" function, they said something to the effect of:

> A spell check is something I do with my local coven, a spelling check is what I do when I'm 
>        reviewing a written document.

Is it more correct to say:

> This paper is horrible!  You didn't even use a spelling check.

as opposed to

> You didn't even use a spell check.

?

Comment: I think that automated spell(ing) checkers are recent enough tools that there's room for language to evolve. It may be too soon to say a definitive "more correct" answer has been established.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that I **check the spelling** of my papers by using the **spell check** function on my word processor.  One describes the process, the other describes the computer function.

Comment: I like this the best because it makes the most sense to me.  I understand you to say that "spell check" is not correct simply because of grammer, but describes a function and is therefore a noun.

Answer (score 3):

*Spell* is recorded in the Oxford English Dictionary as a noun used colloquially to mean ‘a way or mode of spelling a word’. That would suggest that the answer to your question is not that *spelling check* is more ‘correct’ than *spell check*, but that it is more formal.

Comment: Very interesting.  One reason why I asked was because I haven't heard anybody use "spelling check" before.  Perhaps I should read more high brow stuff!

Answer (score 0):

We would say '***spell check***' exclusively in the sense of using a spelling check(-er/ -ing) software, and '***spelling check***' in a generic sense.

That is the convention.